# How does an electricity meter work?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electric-current

I am interested to know how household electricity meters calculate the energy spent in the circuit.

The simplest way to calculate the energy spent is to separately measure the current and the voltage in the line, and integrate their product. However, this may not practically be the most convenient technique.

While a digital electric meter may work in this way (multiply current and voltage, and integrate it over time), analog electric meters (which had a wheel that spun to show the total energy spent) cannot multiply and sum (integrate).

How did the old, analog electricity meters work? How do their wheels spin faster as the household electric circuit consumes more energy per unit time?

And how do the modern digital electricity meters work?

Comment: Why analog circuit cannot multiply sum and integrate? 
There are plenty of electrical circuits doing so

Comment: @kyril Still, doing math like that whether digitally or analog involves solid-state electronics. Actual power meters that are referred to as analog are electromechanical and use coils I believe. I had it described to me once but no longer remember. Something about one coil being turned one way relative to another or something like that. EDIT: Actually, it's on Wikipedia under "Electricity Meter". Two coils, one for voltage and one for current acting on a spinning disc (your dial) that together act as an induction motor.

Comment: @DKNguyen Perhaps not directly related to the OP's question, but you can certainly integrate without solid-state electronics, a simple RC circuit is an integrator...

Comment: I believe this may explain it; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter#Electromechanical

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtModjpxfxM

Comment: They do explain it. Thank you.